# Вопрос по циклам

Tags: циклы, c++

Почему в коде ниже **place_number** в конце равен коду последнего символа?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    int place[3];
    int place_number = 0;
    char place_value;

    while (place_number < 3)
    {
        place_number = place_number + 1;
        cin >> place_value;
        place[place_number] = place_value;
    }

    cout << place[1] << " " << place[2] << " " << place[3] << " " << place_number;
    return 0;
}
```

Пример выполнения:

```
M 
N 
L 
77 78 76 76
```

**UPD**: Вопрос решён!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    main()
    {
        int place[3];
        int place_number = 0;
        char place_value;

        while (place_number < 3)
        {
            cin >> place_value;
            place[place_number] = place_value;
            place_number = place_number + 1;
        }

        cout << place[0] << " " << place[1] << " " << place[2] << " " << place_number;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в коде, в С++ массивы начинаются с 0, а не с 1.
А у вас place_number равен 1 когда первый раз пытаетесь записать в массив.
Измените цикл...

```
while (place_number < 3)
{
    cin >> place_value;
    place[place_number] = place_value;
    place_number = place_number + 1;
}
```

или используйте for

```
for (int place_number = 0; place_number < 3; place_number++) {
    cin >> place_value;
    place[place_number] = place_value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Массив `place` содержит три элемента. Поэтому элемента `place[3]` в нем нет. Но в массивов `с++` отсутствует проверка на границы и запись `place[3]` это просто `(place+3*sizeof(int))`. А там, по этому адресу совершенно случайно оказался `place_number`. И его распечатало.

Comment: Там первый элемент place[0]?

Comment: конечно. это же классический баг начинающих программистов.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы забыли про то, что нумерация массивов начинается с нуля. Вы в теле цикла сначала увеличиваете `place_number` который является индексом текущего элемента, а только потом пишете в `place[place_number]` введенное значение. То есть вы сначала пишете значение в 
`place[1]` затем в `place[2]` а потом в `place[3]` Но `place[3]` у вас нет (массив состоит из трех, а не из четырех элементов), поэтому вы пишете значение уже за пределы массива. Следующие 4 байта (или сколько у вас под `int`) заняты переменной `place_number`. Не уверен, что именно так будет всегда и везде, скорее всего с другим компилятором и другой архитектурой вы получите какой-то иной эффект.